# Selecting a record in SQL based on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, case

I want to select a record based off the "ranking" assigned to it in a column. For example if I have a table that has the following.

```
Sample | Site | Depth_From | Depth_To | Result | Ranking
111    |  AA  |  12        |    15    |  10    |  2
112    |  AA  |  12        |    13    |  8     |  1
113    |  AA  |  13        |    14    |  9     |  1
114    |  AA  |  14        |    15    |  11    |  1
115    |  BB  |  12        |    15    |  5     |  2
```

I want to select the highest ranked sample for each depth interval without having duplicate readings. The expected result would look like.

```
Sample | Site | Depth_From | Depth_To | Result | Ranking
112    |  AA  |  12        |    13    |  8     |  1
113    |  AA  |  13        |    14    |  9     |  1
114    |  AA  |  14        |    15    |  11    |  1
115    |  BB  |  12        |    15    |  5     |  2
```

Note that that AA 12-15 is ignored because there is a higher "ranking" result over the sample interval but BB 15-18 is left as "2" is the highest "ranking" over the interval.

I've tried concatenating the Site and Depth_From and then casing based on ranking but haven't been able to get it to work as yet.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sql server and mysql are two different rdbms products with different implementations of sql. I removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you actually use. Pls also provide the query you tried.

Comment: No worries, I've added sql-server back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the unique Depths for each Site and then use cross apply to select the sample result for each Depth that has the lowest Ranking

```
select
    topRankSamples.*
from ( 
-- getting the unique depth intervals
select distinct Depth_From, Site
from someTable
) DepthInts
cross apply
(
    -- get the lowest ranked sample for each depth interval
    select top 1 Samples.Sample, Samples.Site, Samples.Result. Samples.Ranking
    from someTable as Samples
    where Samples.Depth_From = DepthInts.Depth_From and Samples.Site = DepthInts.Site
    order by Samples.Ranking asc
) topRankSamples
```

Comment: Glad its working as expected. Let me know if you have any questions about the query in the answer.

Comment: actually it's still only treating depth_from as unique, I need it to be a combination of Site and Depth_From to be treated as unique. I've changed to tables in the question so there's now a double up on depth_from but with a different site

Comment: I revised the query so it considers site.